# Rewrite rule with QUERY_STRING don't work

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On Apache server, i need to rewrite mydomain.com/something/?p=value to mydomain.com/something/?page=value

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/p=$ $1?page=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

but don't wok, can help me?

Comment: Is `something` a single URL path segment, as your question would seem to imply? Or can this literally be any URL-path?

Comment: I've just noticed you asked the [same question on StackOverflow yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465786/apache-rewrite-rule-with-query) which already has a very reasonable answer? Was there any issue with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.*)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/p=$ $1?page=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
> ```

There are numerous "errors" here:

- The `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `^(.*)/p=$`, will never match because `p=` does not occur as part of the URL-path (it is part of the query string). The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. So, the above will do nothing for the example URL stated.
- You are using the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in place of the required URL parameter `value` in the *substitution* string. But `QUERY_STRING` is obviously the entire "query string", so would end up constructing a malformed query string of the form: `page=p=<value>`.
- The use of the `QSA` flag results in the original query string on the request being *merged* with the query string you are using in the *substitution* string. So, this would result in `&p=<value>` being appended, which is not what you required. You are looking to replace the existing query string.
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)/p=$ $1?page=` - You are excluding the trailing slash from the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so this would effectively remove the trailing slash from the rewritten URL. This is different to your example.
- You appear to require an internal rewrite (no *external redirect*) and you are "only" changing the name of a single URL parameter. This is something you would ordinarily resolve in your application, rather than a URL rewrite in Apache. (?)

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally "rewrite" the request
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*/)$ $1?page=%1 [L]
```

This matches any URL-path that ends in a slash (as per your example). The `%1` backreference refers to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*, ie. the value of the `p` URL parameter. It is assumed that `p=<value>` is the only URL parameter on the request.

---

> **UPDATE:** it seems not to work... if i call `localhost/list/?p=2` i simply get `localhost/list/?p=2`

Yes, the visible URL does not change, since this is an *internal* "rewrite" (as you appear to be requesting in your question). The URL is *internally* rewritten to `list/?page=2`. (There is also the point that `list/?page=2` is not strictly a valid end-point - it requires further rewriting, perhaps by mod_dir to form a valid request. eg `list/index.php?page=2`?)

If you want the URL to visibly change then maybe you do require an *external* "redirect" after all? For this you need to include a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string and add the `R` (`redirect`) flag. For example:

```
# Externally "redirect" the request
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*/)$ /$1?page=%1 [R=302,L]
```

> if i modify the rule to get `localhost/list/?p=2&?p=2` as below:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]*)$
> RewriteRule (.*/)$ $1&?page=%1 [L]
> ```
>
> i get 'The requested URL `/list/&` was not found on this server.' as '?' cut the rewrite

If you request `localhost/list/?p=2&?p=2` (but why?) then the above directive(s) won't do anything at all since the condition will not match.

Why did you add a `&` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string? (That does not make sense?) That would indeed result in a URL-path of the form `/list/&`, if the rule was processed. But as stated, it wouldn't be processed for the URL you've stated?

Comment: it seems not to work... if i call 'http://localhost/list/?p=2' i simply get 'http://localhost/list/?p=2'

if i modify the rule to get 'http://localhost/list/?p=2&?p=2' as below

'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*/)$ $1&?page=%1 [L]'

i get 'The requested URL /list/& was not found on this server.' as '?' cut the rewrite

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Maybe you do require an external redirect? I've updated my answer. However, the rest of your comment doesn't seem to make sense? Why are you requesting `/list/?p=2&?p=2`?

Comment: Yes, now i know that i need external redirect. Now seems work.
The rest is because my cms ignore the ?p=2 request and go to the first page. If a clic on Next Page I get /?p=2&page=2.
But it was just a curiosity, Thanks